# Extract API calls from Android classes.dex file

Tags: android, disassembly

I've read papers about extracting the API calls made by an android application by dissassembling the classes.dex file with baksmali. Can someone explain or direct me to resources on how one would go about extracting all the API calls in an automated fashion.